# What happens if I install a program on Windows 32 Bit that can only be installed on Windows 64 Bit

Tags: vmware-workstation

I was trying to install VMware Workstation 12 on 32 Bit Windows, I could only install maximum VMware Workstation 10, if I tried to install VMware Workstation 12 on 32 Bit I would get a message saying that the processor in use was not supported.

Also if I try to extract the MSI into the setup and change it to a 32 Bit packet then bypassing the unsupported processor message, will something happen?

Comment: The installer will still install 64-bit images.  64-bit images do not work in 32-bit architectures.  If you want 64-bit VMWare you need a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Ok thanks, my question is if it is not dangerous to do so

Comment: Dangerous?  In what sense?  Even if you were somehow successful in tricking the system to get the package installed, the binaries simply can't be executed.  The OS will just straight-up refuse to do it.

Comment: The point was, to see if you don't harm your computer by installing an unsupported program

Comment: But my point is it's more than just unsupported.  It's just plain not possible.  You can have 64-bit images sitting around on a 32-bit system just fine.  All they are at that point are binary files that can do nothing.  They can't be executed, so it follows that they can't harm your system.

Comment: And then in my opinion it would also be useless, in fact, bypassing the error, errors occurred during the installation

Comment: The whole exercise of trying to install a 64-bit application on a 32-bit system is pretty useless, IMHO.

Comment: If you need 64-bit programs, back up and re-install 64-bit Windows. Windows 11 is now 64-bit only and VMware Workstation (newer versions) install only on 64-bit machines. 32-bit severely hampers memory.  I have VMware Workstation V16 on a Windows 11 Pro host.

Comment: A 32-bit OS expects everything in 32-bit organization.  If you somehow get a 64-bit program to run it won't be able to talk--it will be deaf, blind and dumb.  In other words, of completely no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was trying to install VMware Workstation 12 on 32 Bit Windows, I
> could only install maximum VMware Workstation 10,

You generally (98%+) cannot install a 64-bit program on a 32-bit operating system; that is, not possible.

For installation of VMware Workstation Pro, please see:

[VMware Workstation Installation requirements](https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-pro.html)

> General System Requirements
>
> VMware Workstation runs on standard x86-based hardware with 64-bit
> Intel and AMD processors, and on 64-bit Windows or Linux host
> operating systems. For more detail, see our System Requirements
> documentation.

For a reasonably modern version of VMware Workstation (V10 is very old), you need a 64-bit operating system.

To run a 64-bit guest you need a 64-bit host.

So if your host supports a 64-bit operating system, then back up and install the 64-bit version.

Comment: what are the remaining 2% ?

Comment: There is no black and no white so I do not use absolute numbers. Someone somewhere might make one installation work. Who know.s.

Comment: Giving such a number might suggest possibilities to install a 64  bits program munder a 32 bits OS do exist. Better to say "as far as I know it's not possible..."

Comment: I clarified it for you to also say not possible.

Comment: @John It may be possible to **install** a 64-bit program on a 32-bit OS, if the **installer** itself is a 32-bit program; however, even if the installation succeeds, the program will not run, so it will be useless anyway.

Comment: even if the installation succeeds, the program will not run,   ... And so I have said it is not possible.  The OP should accept the Answer that it cannot be done. Especially for the OP's example of VMware Workstation. That requires a 64-bit OS.

Comment: I don't think it's true that you need a 64-bit host OS to run a 64-bit guest.  IIRC VMware Workstation (at least old versions, before they dropped support for 32-bit host OSes) did allow running a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit host OS as long as the host hardware was x64.

Comment: Very old VMware would run on a 32-bit OS but V12 and up and certainly 14 and up need 64-bit operating systems for sure.  That was clear in the article I posted with my answer